# How can I transform my array to 0 or 1 elements?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 6 0 6 6 6 6]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 5 5 5 0 0 5 5 5 0 2 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6 6 0 0 6 6]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 5 5 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 6 6 0 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 6 6 0 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 0 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 6 6 0 0 0 6 6 0 0 6 6]]
```

what i want is to change the value of every none 0 number to 1.

what i can do:

```
for element in list:
    for sub_element in element:
        if sub_element != 0:
           sub_element = 1
```

How can i do that in numpy?

Comment: `a[a!=0] = 1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a NumPy array `A`:

```
res = A.astype(bool).astype(int)
```

For efficiency, and most use cases, you can keep your array as Boolean, omitting the integer conversion.

This works because `0` is the only integer considered `False`; all others are `True`. Converting a Boolean array to `int` is then a trivial mapping of `False` to `0` and `True` to `1`.

Comment: I checked with `np.unique(A)` and seems to be correct as 0 and 1 are the only values, may you edit the answer to explain how that line works as i didn't understand it, thanks.

Comment: @Nelly, Sure, I added an explanation.

Comment: @RoadRunner, I wouldn't go *that* far. In many cases, I think Boolean arrays are hugely underrated, you don't need the `astype(int)` part most times; it's true NumPy may take a byte to store a Boolean, but when you start storing large arrays in other formats (e.g. HDF5) it plays a part.

Answer (score 5):

If your numpy array is named `a`, you can use something like this:

```
a[a!=0.0] = 1
```

proof:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 10.0])
>>> a
array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   0.,  10.])
>>> a[a!=0.0] = 1
>>> a
array([ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.])
```

This works because `a != 0.0` will return array with `True`/`False` values
where the condition is met and then the assignment is performed only on those
elements where there is `True`:

```
>>> a != 0
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Also, this works with any other condition.